# Scala nested Lists

Tags: python, scala, scala-collections, nested-lists

I’m trying to fetch a value from a nested list in Scala but somehow I’m not able to find a solution.

I’ve created a list as:

```
var list3 = List((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8),(9,10,11,12))
```

I require 7 as the output.

In Python, for the same thing, I’m creating list as

```
list3 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

To get the output as 7, I’m using

```
list3[len(list3) -2][len(list3) -4]
```

Please suggest me how to achieve the same in Scala.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm new to Scala and I tried from my end. I couldn't find a solution that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `productElement` as below

```
scala> var list3 = List((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8),(9,10,11,12))
list3: List[Product with Serializable] = List((1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8), (9,10,11,12))

scala> list3(list3.length -2).productElement(list3.length-4)
res0: Any = 7
```

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz Can you help me understand it better?

Answer (score 3):

`list3` isn't a list-of-lists, it's a list of *tuples*. You can create a list-of-lists as follows:

```
var list3 = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),List(7,8),List(9,10,11,12))
```

Then, the Scala version of your python code would work:

```
scala> list3(list3.size - 2)(list3.size - 4)
res3: Int = 7
```

Comment: I get it. Your answer has given me a better clarity.